# How to make ionic app to be used on mobile and PC browsers?

Tags: javascript, mobile, ionic2

I have a web application that designed by ionic 2 to be used on browser

my web app works fine on mobile screen, but Is possible to make it such as this below picture ?

[image]

If possible, how can I do it ?

Comment: you can manage that by changing your css code and use media queries have a look [here](https://davidwalsh.name/device-state-detection-css-media-queries-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using css media query.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    body {
        width: 500px;
    }
}
```

hope it will work for you.

Or another perfect solution is for you.

Run this command

```
ionic serve --lab
```

After running command, on the right side of the browser, there is a buttuon "Platform", click on it and select your desired platform Android, iOS or Window or all of them.